# IF condition on strings

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a simple code to test the value that was inputted to my constant value.

I declared this code as my constant value.

```
String LetMeThrough = "drunk";
String GotAnID = "drunk";
```

This is the whole code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner DrunkTest = new Scanner(System.in);

    String InputDrunk;
    String InputDrunkAgain;

    String LetMeThrough = "drunk";
    String GotAnID = "drunk";



    System.out.print("Type drunk: ");
    InputDrunk= DrunkTest.next();
    System.out.print("Re Type drunk: ");
    InputDrunkAgain = DrunkTest.next();

    if(InputDrunk == LetMeThrough & InputDrunkAgain == GotAnID){
        System.out.print("You're not DRUNK");
    }
    else
        System.out.print("You're F***** DRUNK");

}}
```

The problem is that if I type "drunk" on both.
I will get "You're F****** DRUNK" instead of the "You're not DRUNK".
When the inputted values is the same as my constant values.

Comment: so many times already answered this question...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it.

Comment: `String.equals()` made me loathe Java as soon as I ran into it the first time.

Comment: Don't change question's title with (SOLVED), to mark question as accepted check this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work , you must use the arrows and the check to rate and validate  the answers you receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use [String::equals](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Freference%2FString_equals_.html&ei=EUgRVYyLL8qvafqdgOAO&usg=AFQjCNEcn5FredqAJGyxPqYX9mnOUNI1jQ&sig2=0DNNJo9iNDmsSyT-Hyp1rQ&bvm=bv.89184060,d.d24) method to compare.

Comment: Thanks, Jordi I got it now :)

Comment: not related with question but: in `Java` variable names MUST start with `lowercase` so `String myString;` only `java classes` start with `UPPERCASE` so `public class Main`

Comment: Oops sorry. I'll remember that :) Thanks Jordi

Comment: you're welcome, is never easy to start, better some help :)